# Binding data from a stored proc and dropdown list to populate a gridview aspx

Tags: asp.net

can anybody help?

I have two stored procs, each calling two separate result tables.

I need to create a dropdown list so when a table is selected it will refresh the page and populate the grid view with the new table result...

at the moment all i have is the connection calling one of the tables on the page load... but i need this populating to the dropdown list also...

```
public void Refreshdata()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Database=WorkstationCells");

    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.uspTargetQuantitesg120";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "g120C";

    sda.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I know similar questions have been answered but i am new to this and not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

> First create a drop down list in your form and set `AutoPostBack=true`

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownlist1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    Width="200px" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownlist1_Changed">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

> `Refreshdata()`

```
void Refreshdata()
 {
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Database=WorkstationCells");

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.uspTargetQuantitesg120";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "g120C";

sda.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

> `Void DropDown()`

```
void DropDown()
    {
        con.Open();
         String str = "Your Query";
        SqlCommand   cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close();
    }
```

> `Page_Load()`

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          DropDown();
            }
        }
```

> `DropDownlist1_Changed()`

```
 protected void DropDownlist1_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks guys i manged to get this to work like this...   protected void 
  
        protected void Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Refreshdata(Dropdownlist1.SelectedValue);
            //refreshes to the new table on drop selection
        }

    }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to bind data to DropDownList in GridView in ASP.Net

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-bind-data-to-DropDownList-in-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx